# Thymeleaf th unless

Tags: html, thymeleaf

in my html i wanna use "th:unless". i wanna compare two coming variable,if any one match with other, i want to hide the button in that raw.

here is my code..

Art-in-Nisantasi-Id
            Art-in-Nisantasi-Text
            Art-in-Nisantasi-Url
            Art-in-Nisantasi-Coordinate

```
<h3>All Contents</h3>
<table border="1">
    <tr align="left">

        <th style="width: 20px;">Art-in-Nisantasi-Id</th>
        <th style="width: 100px;">Art-in-Nisantasi-Text</th>
        <th style="width: 50px;">Art-in-Nisantasi-Url</th>
        <th style="width: 50px;">Art-in-Nisantasi-Coordinate</th>
    </tr>



    <tr th:each="contentType:${contentTypes}">
        <td th:text="${contentType.art_in_nisantasi_id}"></td>
        <td th:text="${contentType.art_in_nisantasi_text}"></td>
        <td th:text="${contentType.art_in_nisantasi_url}"></td>
        <td th:text="${contentType.art_in_nisantasi_coordinate}"></td>

    </tr>


    <div>
        <td
            th:unless="${contentType.art_in_nisantasi_id}+'='+${selectedContent.art_in_nisantasi_id}"></td>
        <td th:attr="data-id=${contentType.art_in_nisantasi_id}">
            <button type="button" class="action-addButton" onclick="show">Ekle</button>

        </td>
    </div>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
   <td th:unless="${contentType.art_in_nisantasi_id == selectedContent.art_in_nisantasi_id}"></td>
```

this td element will be produced or created in dom when both are not equal